# Port Mapping in C# is not working

Tags: c#, upnp, portforwarding

i need to perform port forwarding in a desktop application written in C#

i used this code :

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using NATUPNPLib;

namespace iSpyApplication
{
    public static class NATControl
    {
        public static UPnPNAT NAT = new UPnPNAT();
        private static IStaticPortMappingCollection _mappings;

        public static IStaticPortMappingCollection Mappings
        {
            get
            {
               if (_mappings==null)
               {

                   try
                   {
                       if (NAT.NATEventManager != null)
                        _mappings = NAT.StaticPortMappingCollection;
                   }
                   catch
                   {
                   }
               }

               return _mappings;
            }
         }

        public static bool SetPorts(int wanPort, int lanPort)
        {
           bool b = false;
           int i = 3;
           while (Mappings == null && i > 0)
           {
               Thread.Sleep(2000);
               i--;
           }

           if (Mappings != null)
           {
               try
               {
                   Mappings.Remove(wanPort, "TCP");
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   // do something
               }
               try
               {
                   Mappings.Add(wanPort, "TCP", lanPort, internalIP, true, "iSpy");
                   b = true;
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   // do something
               }
           }

           return b;

        } // method

  } // class    

} // namespace
```

UPnP is enabled in my linksys router

the code is running and not giving any errors or exceptions, however, mapping is simply not happening.

here is how i am testing it:

1. i have an application that listens to an internal port e.g. 8080.
2. i manually add a mapping entry to my router:

   application : HTTP , external port 8080 , internal port 8080, protocol: TCP , internal IP , enabled
3. i request the following URL in my browser: 
   http : // publicIP : externalport /
4. the application receives a socket on the internal port and replies with a message.

i remove the mapping entry and try to add it programmatically

1. the same
2. i run a code that performs mapping
3. the same
4. browser displays the followin message :

   Unable to connect

   Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at
   publicIP:externalPort

i have searched for C# code that performs mapping, and they all look the same.
Why would mapping fail ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you confirm that your testing method works? for example, create a manual portforwarding and test that port

Comment: that's what i did first. manual mapping works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Idea 1**: `IStaticPortMappingCollection.Add` does have a return value, which you should check for errors.

**Idea 2**: Your router may not allow you setting a static route over UPnP.

Run **DeviceSpy** from [UPnP Developer Tools](http://opentools.homeip.net/dev-tools-for-upnp) and look for your router. Its URN ends in `*:InternetGatewayDevice`. Under the device, look for service `WANIPConnection`. Look for the number after the service name. If it is `2`, then you are out of luck. `WANIPConnection` service description (downloadable at the [UPnP website](http://upnp.org/resources/upnpresources.zip)) states at the `PortMappingLeaseDuration`:

> In release 1.0, a value of 0 was used to create a static port
>   mapping. In version 2.0, it is no longer  possible to create static
>   port mappings via UPnP actions. Instead, an out-of-band mechanism is
>   REQUIRED to do so (cf. WWW-administration, remote management or local
>   management).

Even if your `WANIPConnection` is still version `1`, you can use **DeviceSpy** for finding out whether the route is really being set by your code or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Considering Idea1 : in C#, the return type of IStaticPortMappingCollection.Add method is IStaticPortMapping, and it's returning an object that doesn't seem to have errors...
Considering Idea2: i found my router ( Its URN ends in *:InternetGatewayDevice) and under it there is a service called (Layer3Forwarding), LANDevice and WANDevice,they are all version 1, but i found no (WANIPConnection) service!
How can i use Device Spy to check if the route is being set by my code?
Thanks again.

Comment: 1. i am not talking about *output parameter* but *return value* 2. The devices are hierarchic: `WANDevice/WanConnectionDevice/WANIPConnection`. You are looking for `PortMappingNumberOfEntries` and then `GetGenericPortMappingEntry`. You might also try `AddPortMapping` as that's what your code would have to use.

Comment: IStaticPortMapping m = mappings.Add(ExternalPort, Protocol, InternalPort, LocalIP, true, Description) ;   this line of code is from the project : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/110338/UpnpStat-List-and-Modify-Port-Mappings-on-your-UPn  ... i ran the project. No errors, and no EFFECT neither (mapping didn't seem to take place)

Comment: Ok so you are left with **Idea 2**.